# create login for user and admin

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have managed to create login for user but trying to implement an admin login now any help would be appreciated, so far i have:

```
        $query = "
        SELECT
            id,
            username,
            password,
            salt,
            email,
    firstname,
    admin
        FROM users
        WHERE
            username = :username 
    ";


    $query_params = array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username']
    );

    try
    {

        $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
    $ex->getMessage().

        die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage());
    }

    $login_ok = false;
    $row = $stmt->fetch();
    if($row)
    {

        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['password'] .  
        $row['salt']);
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++)
        {
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password .  
            $row['salt']);
        }

        if($check_password === $row['password'])
        {

            $login_ok = true;
        }
    }



    if($login_ok)
    {
        unset($row['salt']);
        unset($row['password']);



    $_SESSION['user'] = $row;
    $_SESSION['admin'] = $admin;




        header("Location: private.php");
        die("Redirecting to: private.php");
    }

    $admin = $row["admin"]==1;

    if($admin){
    header("Location: memberlist.php");
    }

    if(!$admin){
    header("Location: private.php");
    }



    else
    {
        // Tell the user they failed
        print("Login Failed.");
```

In my database i have set the admin field to boolean defualt value as 1.

Comment: Please read about [**How to Ask questions here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: when i login as admin it still goes to normall user page (private.php) if admin logs in i want them to go to membeslist.php. but obviously first the query has to know if user or admin is logging in.

Comment: i cant get admin to login and go to memberlist page

Comment: Format your code, and the answer will be obvious. If the login works, you always redirect; the admin/non-admin redirect logic will never be reached. In fact, you'll end up redirecting even if the login failed.

Comment: but how does the query know if it is admin or user, maybe the query is wrong and not checking for admin

Comment: You'd have to tell us whether the query works as intended, not the other way around. Please format your code, try debugging it (with a debugger), and if you still have problems, read the links above, *then* post your question.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the field type with default value admin and added an if statement and now i have an admin user and a normal user and the pages redirect according the user level.

```
     if($_SESSION['user']['type'] == 'admin') { header("location:  
     memberlist.php");  }

 else
     header("Location: private.php");
     die("Redirecting to: private.php");
    }
```